# Why does this() in an if statement not throw compiler error

Tags: apex, bug, inheritance, constructor

Using 'this();' inside an if statement in a constructor does not throw a compiler error.

It should throw 'Call to 'this()' must be the first statement in a constructor'; 
If it is allowed then it should work but does not in my case.

The code is allowed to run but is calling the base constructor twice which throws a run-time exception. I do not understand why.

Here is a Base class

```
public virtual class CompilerErrorBase {
      protected final Map<String,Integer> Counts;

      public CompilerErrorBase() {
          this.Counts = new Map<String,Integer>();
    }
}
```

This class works

```
public class CompilerWorks extends CompilerErrorBase {
    private final Date aDate;

    public CompilerWorks(Date a, Date b, Date c) {
        this(b);
    }
    public CompilerWorks(Date a, Date b) {
        this();
    }
    public CompilerWorks(Date a) {
        aDate = a;
    }
    public CompilerWorks() {
        aDate = Date.today();
    }
}
```

This class does not

```
public class CompilerErrorExample extends CompilerErrorBase {
    private final Date aDate;
    public CompilerErrorExample(Date a, Date b) {
        if (b == null){
            this();
        }
        else{
            this(b);
        }

    }
    public CompilerErrorExample(Date a) {
        aDate=a;

    }
    public CompilerErrorExample() {
        aDate = Date.today();
    }
}
```

In CompilerErrorExample class the base class constructor is called twice and throws

> System.FinalException: Final variable has already been initialized

I do not understand why CompilerWorks class does not throw same error

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug. Have you opened a case with support?

Comment: Yes I knew it must be a bug.  Since it is not unique to my org I saw no reason to create a support ticket and spend additional time on it.

Comment: Well that's generally how they find out they have bugs in the system.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a bug. A call to an alternative constructor or parent constructor **must** be the first method called in a constructor, as noted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_this.htm):

> When you use the this keyword in a constructor to do constructor chaining, it must be the first statement in the constructor.

It is not allowed, so a compiler bug at best.

Comment: could you use a ternary to try to get around this?

Comment: @CasparHarmer Nope. A call to this or super must be the very first expression. If you need a common initializer, use an instance method.

Comment: Yes, I think I remember trying to use a ternary a while back... as I recall, no joy.